# How to prevent duplicate specific value on Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Can anybody point out to me where is the error I am making here. Basically what I'm trying to do is to prevent duplicate Insertions for the 'level' column where the value is "Juri".

For example, if someone insert the others value (except Juri) it can be inserted.

```
public function tambah()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'is_unique[pengguna.username]', array('is_unique' => '%s sudah ada'));
  
        if( $this->db->where('level' => 'Juri')
            ->get('pengguna')->num_rows())
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('level', 'Level', 'is_unique[pengguna.level]', array('is_unique' => '%s sudah ada'));
        }

   
        if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('pengguna/tambah');
        } else {
            $this->pengguna_model->insert();
            $this->session->set_flashdata('sukses', '<div class="alert bg-success" role="alert">Data berhasil disimpan</div>');
            redirect('pengguna');
        }

    }
```

Comment: [Try the docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data).  They show the syntax for `where()` as: `$this->db->where('level', 'Juri')`, or if you want as an array, `$this->db->where(['level' => 'Juri'])`.

Comment: Does that help? If so I suggest to close this as a typo as it is unlikely to help future visitors.